depuis + passé composé
I came across this sentence in a French text:

Le charme du Limousin, ce sont enfin les bords de la Vienne qui traverse le département de part en part, alimentant de ses eaux noires - toutes celles du pays le sont - les mille petites industries artisanales, qui, depuis des siècles, ont constitué la seule richesse économique de la région.

I am wondering why depuis is followed by the passé composé and not the present.
Is the implication that the industries no longer constitute the region's only economic wealth?
How is the wording different in meaning from 'qui, pendant des siècles, constituaient'...?

Would "for centuries" require a particular tense in English or French?

No, the implication is, on the contrary, that this state of affairs does go on; but this is subject to an inference: since "depuis des siècles", without an upper limit, implies "until nowadays", and it is clear that such a situation as the economic ressources of a region cannot be changed from one day the next; so one understands that it goes on. Another clue is the "présent participle" "alimentant". This verbal form, reckoned with as a "co-verb", contributes with the main verb in the matrix clause ("traverse", in the present) to the denotation of a unique situation; this means that, "traverser" being in the "présent de vérité générale" the fact that the river supplies water to the industries is as well "une vérité générale", something true in the past, still true today and bound to be true in the future. (Le participe présent comme co-verbe - Michael Herslund).
However, the "passé composé" can be used with two limits, and then it is a perfect equivalent to the English past.

Les cultivateurs ont travaillé leurs terres depuis des siècles jusque dans les années 50 du siècle dernier au moyen de chevaux et de bœufs.

When no upper limit is given, it is undecided whether the action is still going on at the time when the sentence is uttered, and you must rely on the  context to determine the time of the action.

Il ont creusé cette tranchée depuis hier matin. (They might still be digging, or they might be finished.)

Il ont creusé cette tranchée depuis hier matin, et ils ne pensent pas avoir fini ce soir. (They are still digging.)

Il ont creusé cette tranchée depuis hier matin, et maintenant ils n'ont plus rien à faire. (They have stopped digging.)


Le présent duratif serait plus explicite (Les valeurs du présent).
Why use the "present" rather than the "passé composé", or vice versa, is simply a matter of personal choice.
If you use the "imparfait", in this linguistic context, you express an action that extends fully in the past (valeurs de l'imparfait (Une action située dans le passé)).  However, you'd have to change the the participial clause because providing water to the industries is not something happening in the present, whereas the river still extends through the region ("co-verb" question introduced above).

Le charme du Limousin, ce sont enfin les bords de la Vienne qui traverse le département de part en part, alimentant de ses eaux noires** - toutes celles du pays le sont - les mille petites industries artisanales, qui, depuis des siècles, ont constitué la seule richesse économique de la région.


Le charme du Limousin, ce sont enfin les bords de la Vienne qui traverse le département de part en part, et qui alimentait de ses eaux noires - toutes celles du pays le sont - les mille petites industries artisanales, qui, depuis des siècles, constituaient la seule richesse économique de la région.


I do not agree with the comment stating passé composé is a tense for an ongoing action (like present tense); it doesn't work like present continuous in English.
In light of the extract I see now, passé composé fits here because it is a definite action located in the past (e.g.: from century X to century Y).
Présent wouldn't fit because we are clearly located in the past, with no tie to present tense: those industries aren't the region's sole economical asset anymore.
However, we could say:

Ces boutiques artisanales constituent depuis [optional: des années] le charme de la région.

Because we'd be talking about a landscape still relevant today. Depuis without a time indicator implies a period mentioned earlier.
